# Как правильно экранировать строку c regexp?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, qregexp

Есть строка со сложным выражением для парсинга email. Ни как не могу осилить ее экранирование.

Пробовал:

```
1. r''' 
2. r'
3. ''' 
4. """
```

Первый вариант экранирует, но регулярка становится нерабочей.

Само выражение (Официальный стандарт, известен как RFC 2822):

```
    str = r'(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'
*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b
\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9]
(?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\
[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\.){3}
(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*
[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]
|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])'
```

Answer (score 2):

Нашел более простую строку, она без проблем экранируется

```
str = r'''[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)\b'''
```